# Generate XL report from datatable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, reporting-services, xlsx, sql-server-openxml

Currently we are using OpenXML to generate an XL report from a datatable (ADO.NET) which is fetching data from a SQL server database. Report has approximately 500K records and it is taking close to 10minutes to generate the report hence looking for an alternative solution which support .NET Core.

Any opensource components or solutions to generate XL report quickly which support .NET core ?

Comment: This is related with how you written your codes. I think the openxml is good to use.

Comment: agree but it is taking time since we need create row by row ...